# PRISM and Caliburn combined

Tags: silverlight, prism, caliburn

I am already using Prism, especially the following areas: EventAggregator, RegionManager, Commanding, Dependency Injection (through Unity obviously) 
Have you used Prism in combination with Caliburn? 
Which benefits did it offer you?
How does Caliburn integrate with Silverlight's Navigation framework?
And would you recommend using both frameworks simultaneously? (obviously it depends on your scenario, I'm specifically referring to a LOB application, with a lot of users)

Comment: I recently introduced Caliburn into my Prism application and have found it very worthwhile. I haven't used much more than the IPresenter stuff, actions and view discovery yet, but it's all worked seamlessly so far.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Caliburn actually has a component that adds integration with Prism.  Here's a link to the docs that should provide you with some resources http://caliburn.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=BlogsArticlesProjects&referringTitle=Documentation